# Why is the start level of org.eclipse.osgi -1?

Tags: eclipse, osgi

As [this article](https://eclipsesource.com/de/blogs/2009/06/10/osgi-and-start-levels/) says, a start level is simply a non-negative integer value. But I checked the start level of "org.eclipse.osgi" in **\configuration\org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator\bundles.info**

`org.eclipse.osgi,3.18.100.v20220817-1601,plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.18.100.v20220817-1601.jar,-1,true`

-1 ? Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the value of the `BundleInfo.NO_LEVEL` constant - which means this bundle doesn't have a start level.

`org.eclipse.osgi` contains the `EclipseStarter` class which contains the `main` entry point. It is called by Java rather than being started by the OSGi framework.